# Unable to find a specification for `Google/SignIn`

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to follow this tutorial but i cant get cocoapods to work:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

My pod file:

```
target 'GoogleSigninDemo' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
end
```

I've only tried using cocoapods twice now and so far it has been pretty unpleasent. I have noticed that if i replace the pod 'Google/SignIn' with another pod it seems to work.

pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon.git'  
for example.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "/" in the pod name.
Try this instead :

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.0'
```

Anyway, whenever you need to use CocoaPods, check out the CocoaPods page for the pod you are using : https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn